# Is nudity allowed in historical nonfiction?

Tags: legal, non-fiction, historical, artwork

I have written a historical nonfiction account of a nudist camp that I went to with my family as a teenager. The camp later hosted the Miss Nude America contest and became extremely well known.

My story has many images which feature nudity. Is this allowed?

Comment: You would risk revealing their power levels, along with their nude pictures. That is treason, [treason is punishable by death](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Paranoia).

Comment: LOL I love the color that certain contributors bring to the table. Let us never lose our ability to think along strange and bizarre paths!

Comment: Allowed by whom?  Your publisher?  Amazon's Kindle store?  Libraries?  The people in the images (if they're photos)?  The camp?

Answer (score 8):

Do you have photo permissions from every person in every picture? If you don't, your question is irrelevant. You can't just publish pictures of other people without their permission. Nude pictures are particularly sensitive.

Comment: "Jounalistic" use doesn't require permissions.  Whether this book would qualify might require an expensive court case to settle...

Comment: @ZeissIkon This is more of a topic for law stack exchange, but as far as I know in some countries it might be problematic to show clearly identifiable faces of non-celebrities without permission, even in a "journalistic" context. Especially when you also show their genitalia.

Answer (score 2):

So long as you label the book correctly, and sell it in the proper categories (i.e. don't label it or market in a way that pitches it to children), and it doesn't includes sexual images of children below legal age, there shouldn't be any problem with non-sexual images of nudity.

*Any* images of nude children are likely to arouse some negative sentiment from certain people (even the once-iconic "baby in the bath" photos are now often demonized), so you may want to get an opinion from a lawyer before publishing, to ensure you're clear of (legally defined) child pornography.  You may also want to choose carefully the market you offer to -- for similar reasons.